# How to create random incongruous shapes that don't overlap each others in P5.js

Tags: processing, p5.js

I'm looking to create shapes like this :
https://www.lucegallard.com/?lightbox=dataItem-isiz1h39
But they have to be generated at random and never overlap. It would be too easy to just use beginShape() and curveVErtex(x,y), etc. 
Plus the result would we static, it needs to be changed easily and randomly. My question is "is there a function to create 'weird' ellipses?" or "Could anyone help me with an algorithm to achieve this?"

Thanks allot in advance!

Comment: "Could anyone help me with an algorithm to achieve this?" Unfortunately, not on this site. This site is for debugging code, not creating code. Can you show what you've tried and where you got stuck, to make this question a bit more on topic?

Comment: So far I only use beginShape() and curveVErtex(x,y), etc. but I'm looking for a way to make the creation of the shapes quicker and random. I could do so with an algorithm that includes complex interaction between each shapes but I came here to ask about a function to create "weird" ellipses and if there is a collision factor I could build into the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stack Overflow isn't really designed for general "how do I do this" type questions. It's for specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. But I'll try to help in a general sense:

You need to [break your problem down into smaller pieces](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/how-to/program) and take those pieces on one at a time. Try to create a program that just generates a single random shape. Then try to add a second randomly-generated shape that doesn't intersect with the first shape.

Think about how you would describe this program to somebody who can't see the website you've linked in your post. Try to describe it in as much detail as you can. Pretend you have a friend who has never seen what you're talking about. Can you write down a set of steps that this friend could follow to draw what you're talking about? When you have those steps written down, that's an algorithm that you can start thinking about implementing with code.

A simple check would be for each new point you generate, check whether it's inside any previous shapes. If so, go back and pick a different new point. That will at least get you started going in a direction.

If you get stuck, please post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) along with a more specific technical question. Good luck.